# using `purrr::map` with compose functions

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to know how to use `purrr::map` where `.f` is a composition of two different functions.

First, let's create a list on which to map a composite function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create a list
x <- list(mtcars, tibble::as_tibble(iris), c("x", "y", "z"))

# extracting class of objects
purrr::map(.x = x, .f = class)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "character"
```

Now let's say I want to extract the *first* element of the `class` of each element in the list:

```r
# this works but uses `map` twice
purrr::map(.x = x, .f = class) %>%
  purrr::map(.x = ., .f = `[[`, i = 1L)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "tbl_df"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "character"
```

That works, but I want to avoid using `map` twice and would like to compose a function that can extract class and its first element in a single step. So I tried to compose such a function but it doesn't play nicely with `map`

```r
# error

purrr::map(.x = x, .f = purrr::compose(class, `[[`, i = 1L))
#> Can't convert an integer vector to function

# no error but not the expected output

purrr::map(.x = x, .f = purrr::compose(class, `[[`), i = 1L)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "character"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't `map(x, ~ first(class(.x)))` work

Comment: Or using compose: `purrr::map(x, purrr::compose(first, class))` or `purrr::map(x, purrr::compose(~.[[1]], class))`. You can't really pass different parameters to different parts of the function in compose from outside the composition.

Comment: @akrun That worked! `purrr::map(x, ~class(.x)[[1]])` works as well if I was hell-bent on using `[[`. Can you post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are using the `~`, just wrapping the `first` would get the expected output

```
library(purrr)
map(x, ~ first(class(.)))
```

Comment: `.x` doesn't need the `x`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Sorry, didn't get your comment.  Here 'x' is the `list` object

Comment: `map(x, ~ first(class(.)))` gave me the same output as  `map(x, ~ first(class(.x)))`

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Yes, that is a true, and in the `?map` it says `For a single argument function, use .` It can be either `.` or `.x`. `.x` becomes relevant when there are two arguments in `map2`.  I didn't want to change the arguments in both `map` and `map2`, so used `.x`

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I find that it is better to use `.x` inside `~` lambda functions, because it distinguishes it from `.` used in magrittr pipe `%>%`. Consider `mtcars %>% map_at( ncol(.), ~.x*100 )`. Writing it this way makes it immediately obvious which pronoun is associated with the pipe and which is associated with the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

We can directly use `compose()` without the formula syntax:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- list(mtcars, tibble::as_tibble(iris), c("x", "y", "z"))

map(x, compose(first, class))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "tbl_df"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "character"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From `?compose`

> compose(..., .dir = c("backward", "forward"))
>
> **...**  Functions to apply in order (from right to left by default) etc ...
>
> **.dir** If "backward" (the default), the functions are called in the reverse order, from right to left, as is conventional in mathematics. If "forward", they are called from left to right.

so we just need to inverse the functions order. Also `compose` doesn't know `i=1L` belong to which function so `compose` will attach it to the last function in this case `class`, so we need to defined `i=1L` explecitly to the intended function.

```
purrr::map(.x = x, .f = purrr::compose(~.x[[1]], class))
[[1]]
[1] "data.frame"

[[2]]
[1] "tbl_df"

[[3]]
[1] "character"
```